# Why is JavaScript Applet Pulling Same JPG's Instead of Pulling 3 Different Ones?

Tags: java, javascript, html, applet, jpeg

Javascript applet is pulling the same picture for all three applets on this page.

http://www.techmobile.com/javalayout10.html

This should not be happening Each applet should have a different picture.

Here are the links to the pics

http://techmobile.dyndns-home.com:8080/branding/applet_splash_sosr.jpg

http://techmobile.dyndns-home.com:8080/branding/applet_splash_sost.jpg

http://techmobile.dyndns-home.com:8080/branding/applet_splash_sosh.jpg

I've changed name of the JPG's and the path to each of them - imageURL="http://www.techmobile.com/branding/mobile.jpg

But the applets still pull the same image.

I've put one applet on a page at a time and still the same pic is pulled by the applet.

Why are the java applets loading the same pic? Is this in the javascript code? Is it because the script and the pics are behind the 8080?

Any insight is much appreciated!

Comment: *"all three applets on this page"*  There are ***no*** Java applets in that page.

Answer (score 0):

Your file, 'embed.js', is full of references to elements by CSS ID.  CSS IDs have to be unique within a document, so you can't have more than one element on the same page with the same ID.

I'm not sure what is the expected browser behaviour when it encounters multiple elements with the same ID, but I wouldn't be surprised to see these results, where content is copied to all elements with the common ID.

Comment: Thanks! I've tried changing the CSS ID's with no luck. I just put a 1,2 and 3 after the CSS ID. No change. Does the CSS ID have to change in the JavaScript?

Comment: Yes, embed.js is generating elements and adding them to the document, but if you call it multiple times it will add the same ID multiple times.